# Best Image Format for storing Binary Image in Java

Tags: image, image-processing, format

I am trying to build an `Image Processor` App Image in `Java` that work with `Black-White` Image. So my App should read many Black-White Image but the time of reading image is very long Because Images are stored in JPEG format and have big size.

Question : What is the Best `Image Format` (not TXT) for storing Black-White Image that was readable in Java with Best time?

Comment: This is neither a Java nor a programming question

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
    import javax.imageio.*;
    import java.awt.image.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class timedimageread
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            BufferedImage img;
            long startTime;
            long endTime;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.jpg"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("jpg: " + (endTime - startTime) );

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.bmp"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("bmp: " + (endTime - startTime) );

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.gif"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("gif: " + (endTime - startTime) );

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.png"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("png: " + (endTime - startTime) );

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.tif"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("tif: " + (endTime - startTime) );

                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.jpg"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("jpg: " + (endTime - startTime) );

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.bmp"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("bmp: " + (endTime - startTime) );

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.gif"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("gif: " + (endTime - startTime) );

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.png"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("png: " + (endTime - startTime) );

          startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.tif"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("tif: " + (endTime - startTime) );

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.jpg"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("jpg: " + (endTime - startTime) );

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.bmp"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("bmp: " + (endTime - startTime) );

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.gif"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("gif: " + (endTime - startTime) );

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.png"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("png: " + (endTime - startTime) );

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blackandwhite.tif"));
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("tif: " + (endTime - startTime) );

        }
    }
```

output:
jpg: 156
bmp: 0
gif: 16
png: 16
tif: 0
jpg: 31
bmp: 0
gif: 16
png: 0
tif: 15
jpg: 16
bmp: 0
gif: 0
png: 16
tif: 0

you can extend the code or use a larger picture to get better results, but my assumption is that .bmp (I used 256 color, but you could reduce that) processes quickly most reliably.

Comment: This answer is unclear. What does this code do exactly?